# How to recognize a certain zone in a image

Tags: vb.net, ocr, solver, sudoku

I'm wondering if it's possible to detect the grid in this image and then output the letters in each cells? (sorry if it's unclear, and I know this image is a game but it Wil be for a sudoku solver)
[image from words blitz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAvpt.jpg)

I know I'll need to use OCR but how to detect the position?

Comment: What would you class as the position?  Row/Column in the grid, pixel x/y or something else?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You will need an AI and a big ram to do this . I dont suggest you to continue this project , its very difficult

Comment: For the output something like row 1 column 1 : "4"